# Access.Log Analyzer

Tags: statistics, logging, analyzer

Just a quick question. I use Ubuntu as a server and as a desktop. Does anyone have any ideas for a nice access.log analyzer? It could be a program that I download to the desktop or the server. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

If You are looking for something light, You can check command line tool for log analyzing called [Go Access](http://goaccess.prosoftcorp.com).

On Ubuntu/Debian just type:

```
sudo apt-get install goaccess
```

It looks like this:

[image]

Comment: It's also in the epel repository. For Red Hat.

Answer (score 3):

[AwStats](http://awstats.sourceforge.net/) is a quite popular choice and [here are instructions for Ubuntu](http://ubuntu-tutorials.com/2008/01/16/configuring-awstats-on-ubuntu-server/)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [Nihuo](http://www.loganalyzer.net) is suitable for you.